# Revolve 2D set of points and calculate volume

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, interpolation

I have a set of points, defining some 2D object (a cross-section).
Here is an example:

```
points={{0, 0}, {14, 0}, {14.5, 1}, {15, 2}, {0, 16}}
```

To visualize the object:

```
ListLinePlot[points,Frame->True,FrameLabel->{"Radius","y-axis"}]
```

I would like to revolve the cross-section around the y-axis to obtain the volume of the 3D body. I would finally like to calculate fractional volumes of the 3D body by integrating over slices of the entire 3D object such as the slice radius 14 to 15.

My approach thus far was as follows (including a description of why I think it failed):
The points have not always incrementing x values, therefore I cannot use Interpolation to generate an interpolating function and do the revolution as follows:

```
interpol=Interpolation[2Dpoints]
partialVolumes=NIntegrate[interpol[x]^2,{x,0,radius}]*Pi/@Table[radius,{radius,0,16}]
```

There are tons of examples of revolving functions, but non starting from discrete points describing an object.

Comment: You can create an interpolation from the reals to real points with: `path = First@FindCurvePath@Standardize@points;
curve = Interpolation[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, points[[path]]], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];`. Check:
`ParametricPlot[curve[t], {t, 1, Length@path}]`.
Then, I believe you should be able to compute the integral by summing: `Pi*NIntegrate[
   curve[t][[1]]^2*curve'[t][[2]], {t, 1, Length@path}] // Abs` however, it seems to be wrong. I'm not sure why, but I believe it's still a possible start with a mistake to correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We best use cylinder coordinates to tackle this task. Toward this aim we define the x value, that is the radius, as a function of y:

```
points={{0, 0}, {14, 0}, {14.5, 1}, {15, 2}, {0, 16}};    
fx[y_] = Interpolation[Reverse /@ Rest[points], InterpolationOrder -> 1][y]
Plot[fx[x], {x, 0, 16}]
```

[image]

The volume is then obtained by integrating the circular slices over the height, the y direction:

```
NIntegrate[Pi fx[y]^2, {y, 0, 16}]
(*4620.24*)
```

If we only want to integrate from slice radius 14 to 15:

```
NIntegrate[Pi fx[y]^2, {y, 14, 15}]
(*8.41498*)
```

**Addendum**

If you have a min and a maximum value for the radius, depending on y, you define 2 functions fxmin and fxmax like e.g.:

From the original data:

```
Graphics[Line[{{7, 0}, {14.5, 1}, {15, 2}, {0, 8}, {7, 1}, {7, 0}}],  Frame -> True]
```

[image]

we get fmin, fmax by:

```
fxmin[y_] = 
 Interpolation[Reverse /@ {{7, 0}, {7, 1}, {0, 8}}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1][y]
fxmax[y_] = 
 Interpolation[Reverse /@ {{7, 0}, {14.5, 1}, {15, 2}, {0, 8}}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1][y]

Plot[{fxmin[y], fxmax[y]}, {y, 0, 8}]
```

[image]

Now we only have to integrate up the slices that have now a hole:

```
NIntegrate[Pi (fxmax[y]^2 - fxmin[y]^2), {y, 0, 8}]
(*1961.92*)
```

Comment: Why `2Pi` and not just `Pi` ?

Comment: I am sorry. Maybe my question was not clear enough. The object might be more complicated like this. Such that y simple x-y transformation does not do the trick. My points were only an example. It could look like Graphics[Line[{{7, 0}, {14.5, 1}, {15, 2}, {0, 8}, {7, 1}, {7, 0}}], 
 Frame -> True] as well

Comment: @anderstood, thank's, was an error, I correted it.

Comment: Simply define 2 functions:_ fxmin[y] and fxmax[y] and integrate from fxmin to fxmax.

Comment: Have you seen my comment further up? There I provided an example for which your solution does not work. I am interested in any shape that I want to revolve to generate some kind of roundly shaped 3D objects. These objects I have to split radially to generate fractional volumes.

Comment: TO help you understand my comment above, I added your new case to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is the also a way to do this using MeshRegion?

Comment: From the help of MeshRegion: "A strictly 3D MeshRegion is a collection of polyhedral volumes" Therefore, a MeshRegion can only approximate a rotation body.

Comment: I did not find help on how to rotate a 2D MeshRegion to obtain a 3D MeshRegion. Also, I think your solution is calculating the volume or fractional volumes as slices in the same direction as the rotation is done?! Maybe also here my question was unclear. I have to calculate fractional volumes perpendicular to the axis of rotation. I think the MeshRegion approach would be easier because it should not rely on transformation of the axis and splitting the geometry in "upper" and "lower" section.

Comment: The area of a slice is Pi radius^2 Pi. If you only want a fraction, e.g. half, the area would be 1/2 Pi radius^2. If the slice has a hole: 1/2 Pi (radiuse1^2- radius2^2). If you want a MeshRegion, you would have to calculate points on its surface but I do not have experience with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use a formula for the volume of a cone with base radii `a` and `b` and height `h`

$$\frac{1}{3} \pi  h \left(a^2+a b+b^2\right)$$

```
v[a_, b_, h_] := Pi h/3 (a^2 + a b + b^2)
v[14, 29/2, 1] + v[29/2, 15, 1] + v[15, 0, 14]
```

Resulting in
$$\frac{4412 \pi }{3}$$